# Why is my webcrawler throughput so low when parallel connections is over 10K?

Tags: c, web-crawler, libcurl

I have implemented a webcrawler with libcurl and libev. My intention was to make a high performance crawler that uses all available bandwidth. I have succeeded in making a crawler that can sustain over 10,000 parallel connections. However, the stats for bandwidth usage are not all that impressive. Here is some example output from `vnstat`:

```
                          rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                    32.86 GiB  |        3.12 GiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max          747.99 Mbit/s  |    25.73 Mbit/s
      average           15.69 Mbit/s  |     1.49 Mbit/s
          min            2.62 kbit/s  |    12.29 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                   33015363  |        23137442
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max              68804 p/s  |       28998 p/s
      average               1834 p/s  |        1285 p/s
          min                  5 p/s  |           5 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                299.95 minutes
```

As you can see my average download speed is only 15.69 Mbps while the network bandwidth can support much more. I do not understand why the application is downloading so slowly and yet still maintaining over 10K connections in parallel. Is this something to do with the URLs that are being downloaded? If I repeatedly download [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) and [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com) I can achieve speeds of up to 7 Gbps. With general crawling though the speed is as shown above.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: We need to see your code. Please edit your question and post your code in a code block here.

Comment: One clue is **average bytes** versus **average packets**. Notice that average packets for RX is about 1.5x average packets for TX, but average bandwidth is 10x. The reason for the difference is that the average RX packet is about 7x larger than the average TX packet. **Bits per second** is limited by the connection speed. **Packets per second** is limited by processor speed. Handling lots of small packets from 10000 connections takes a lot more processor power than downloading full-sized packets from a single connection to Google.